# Removing data from multiple excel files

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have two excel files. There is some common data in both the files. I want to get a new excel file which only has non redundant data. I am reading data from excel files using apace POI (Java). Any help on the algorithm that can be used to remove the redundant data (since there are more than 10,000 rows in each excel file). Thanks.

Comment: Why POI, copy paste all in single sheet and use remove duplicate option

Comment: I can't. The user uploads the excel and I need to edit the excel file the program itself. Anyways, thanks

Answer (score 0):

copy all the data in HashSet(). and write it in another file.